# listview with webview inside,and there is edittext in webview,when it has focused ,it couldn't lose

Tags: android, listview, webview, android-edittext

i'm trying to create a ListView with WebView inside, then every webview load url such as www.baidu.com which webpage has "input" element ,it has problem. when i touch the edittext ,it focused and input method popup , then touch any area outside of edittext ,it has no response.(in the webview,it has no response,but other webview items in the listview has)
this is my code:

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BAdapter adapter = new BAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getLayoutInflater());
    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK) );
    listview.setDividerHeight(2);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

BAdapter  extends BaseAdapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent,false);
    webview = (WebView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.baidu.com");
    return convertView;
}
```

main_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" > 
   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

thinks!